# How to use (.).media.tv.Program in AndroidX or Android Support Library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tv, androidx

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/tv/Program) says that `Program` (the one in the support library and the one in AndroidX) is

> A convenience class to access TvContractCompat.Programs entries in the system content provider.
>
> This class makes it easy to insert or retrieve a program from the system content provider, which is defined in TvContractCompat.

but when I try to use a `Program` retrieved from the provider, I get errors:

```
Program program = getProgram();
String description = program.getDescription();
String title = program.getTitle();
```

> BaseProgram.getTitle can only be called from within the same library (com.android.support:support-tv-provider)

Is this a bug in the support library? Is it an unintended inheritance of the restriction placed on BaseProgram? It makes little sense to me that the description should be public, but the title should have restricted access.

Can I safely ignore this error as reported by Android Studio?